# Do Asians perform less well in football just because of the body condition?

Tags: football

Currently, Asian football players are rare in some top league over the world, in World Cup Asian teams are also rare to have good result, is it just because of the natural body condition? Or just because the football development starts late?

Comment: I'm going with later development. If that's really the case, I don't know. But I don't see what natural body condition would give them a disadvantage. Do you mean to say they are smaller? 
Anyway, Japan played two friendlies againts Holland & Belgium in 2013 as preparation for the 2014 world cup, and played very well those two games. Based on that I kinda was dissapointed by their performance in Brazil later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, it's only a question of time and experience. Asian movement is very young but in the world competitions, nations such as South Korea, Japan have got some good result in the past. In the North America USA, Canada and other nations have got results a little better than Asian nations.

I think, as an Asian leads in the cricket field or on ping pong table, can lead in the football field as well. Maybe in the future, but it's possible.

Consider only Word Cup Championship:

**South Korea:**

- 1954 - First round
- 1986 - First round
- 1990 - First round
- 1994 - First round
- 1998 - First round
- 2002 - 4th place
- 2006 - First round
- 2010 - Top 16
- 2014 - First round

**Japan:**

- 1998 - First round
- 2002 - Top 16
- 2006 - First round
- 2010 - Top 16
- 2014 - First round

Other nations at least in the Top 16

- Saudi Arabia - 1994 - Top 16
- North Korea - 1966 - Top 8

Finally, the body condition can't influence the weak results.